How to use xxhash in hashlib.file_digest?
I want to quickly compute hash values of large files on disk to compare them to one another.
I'm using the following:
 import hashlib
 def sha256sum(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        return hashlib.file_digest(f, 'sha256').hexdigest()

But I'd like to use xxhash since I hear it's faster. This doesn't work:
import hashlib
def xxhashsum(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        return hashlib.file_digest(f, 'xxhash').hexdigest()

Is there a version that would?

Try like this:
import xxhash
import hashlib

def xxhashsum(filename, algo="xxh128"):
    if algo not in xxhash.algorithms_available:
        raise NotImplementedError
    digest = getattr(xxhash, algo)
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        return hashlib.file_digest(f, digest).hexdigest()


Perfect, thank you!
